# Facebook Login With Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-java-api

i need help to integrate facebook with my android app

my manifest are this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.erus.trufes">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i have a button in layout file:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

and my main activity are like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

i am not understanding the tutorial of the facebook developer web page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Have you already created the app on Facebook? https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android

Comment: then you need to understand the facebook developer web page or specify where you went wrong

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented facebook login here:

**https://github.com/ananth10/SocialSignIn** - just go through it. hope it will really help you out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try newest firebase authentification. Follow [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login) it'is quite simple.. and the best is you can monitor it in the console realtime.